# Given $(X,d)$ a metric space, show that $A = \{y \in X : 1 < d(x,y) < 2\}$ is open.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

To show that $A = \{y \in X : 1 < d(x,y) < 2\}$ is open we have to show that $\forall y \in A, \exists r>0: B(y,r) \subseteq A$.

Given $y \in A$, how can I find $r$ such that if $d(y,z) < r$ then $2 < d(x,z) < 3?\ $  i.e $z \in B(y,r) \Rightarrow z \in A$.

Comment: Draw a picture. It will help to see how to construct the desired open balls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select $r = \min \{ d (x, y) - 1, 2 - d (x, y) \}$. Note that both of the quantities are positive, since it is given that $1 < d (x, y) < 2$. We claim that $B (y, r) \subseteq A$.

Let $z \in B (y, r)$. Then $d (y, z) < \min \{ d (x, y ) - 1, 2 - d (x, y) \}$.

By triangle inequality, $d (x, z) \le d (x, y) + d (y, z)$. We know that $d (y, z) < 2 - d (x, y)$, so $d (x, y) + d (y, z) < d (x, y) + (2 - d (x, y)) = 2$. Therefore, $d (x, z) < 2$.

By triangle inequality again, $d (x, z) \ge d (x, y) - d (z, y)$. We know that $d (z, y) = d (y, z) < d (x, y) - 1$, so $d (x, y) - d (z, y) > d (x, y) - (d (x, y) - 1) = 1$. Therefore, $d (x, z) > 1$.

Thus, $1 < d (x, z) < 2 \implies z \in A$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

The open sphere
$$
S(x,r)=\{y\in X\,|\,d(x,y)<r\}
$$
centered at $x$ of radius $r$ is an open set by definition. The set
$$
\bar S(x,r)=\{y\in X\,|\,d(x,y)\leq r\}.
$$
is closed because if $d(x,z)=d>r$ the open sphere $S(x,\rho)$ has empty intersection with $\bar S(x,r)$ if $\rho<d-r$.

So, $A=S(x,2)\setminus\bar S(x,1)$ is the complement of a closed set inside an open set, thus open.

Comment: I don't think the equality $
\overline{S(x,r)}=\{y\in X\,|\,d(x,y)\leq r\}
$ 
holds for any metric space $(X,d)$

Comment: @PeterSampodiras, you are right if the space $X$ isn't too nice. But the argument is easily fixed. I edited my reply

Answer (score 0):

If you allow continuity, $d_x:X\to\Bbb{R}$ defined by $d_x(y) =d(x, y) $ is a continuous map.

Then $A=d_x^{-1}(1, 2) $

$(1, 2) \subset \Bbb{R}$ open and $A$ is the continuous pre-image of an open set.